# Unable to add table data in table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, html-table, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a todo list type web app but unable to add table data in to my table body
I've search alot as well as I try to console log every element still this bug is coming in my project.
datas, data, element and key all this variable giving expected output but I think my logic is wrong somewhere.

my code is as follows:

```
let id, name, rank, year, unit, place, incident, photo, add, table;

id = document.getElementById("id");
name = document.getElementById("name");
rank = document.getElementById("rank");
year = document.getElementById("year");
unit = document.getElementById("unit");
place = document.getElementById("place");
incident = document.getElementById("incident");
photo = document.getElementById("photo");
add = document.getElementById("add");
table = document.getElementById("table");

add.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = [
    {
      id: id.value,
      name: name.value,
      rank: rank.value,
      year: year.value,
      unit: unit.value,
      place: place.value,
      incident: incident.value,
      photo: photo.value,
    },
  ];
  createTable(data);
});

const createTable = (data) => {
  let datas = Object.keys(data[0]);
  generateTable(table, datas);
  generateTableHead(table, datas);
};

const generateTableHead = (table, data) => {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
};

const generateTable = (table, data) => {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      console.log(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
};
```

I'm following following tutorial
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/html-table/

**Getting following output**

[image: nun]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>try this `for...of` instead of `for...in`:</strike>   REVERT

## update

@RahulGurujala after paying more attention to details in the tutorial you are doing, Just change this (explenation below):

```js
const createTable = (data) => {
  let datas = Object.keys(data[0]);
  generateTable(table, datas);
  generateTableHead(table, datas);
};
```

to this:

```js
const createTable = (data) => {
  let datas = Object.keys(data[0]);
  generateTable(table, data); // notice i'm sending the data array and not only the datas arr with the names only
  generateTableHead(table, datas);
};
```

You are sending only key name array to both functions (`generateTable` and `generateTableHead`) when you need to send key names only to the `generateTableHead` and data to the `generateTable`

Comment: @RahulGurujala Check my updated answer. Hope it's helpful